# Why does make not use my explicit rules when implicit rule is also in use?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have (old suffix type) rules inside my Makefile for .c and .o files. The problem is that when i run `make all` those rules are not used and instead the implicit rules are used.

If i run `make all -r` then it will tell me `make: *** No rule to make target...` which is expected since i have intentionally not added explicit rules for program1...3.

In order to fix this issue i can add explicit rules for program1...3:

```
program1: program1.o
```

So a solution is not what i am after here. Just an explanation.

```
all: program1 program2 program3
.o:
    @echo What is going on 1
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $(OUT)/$@

.c.o:
    @echo What is going on 2
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Why does make use implicit rules in the current case even though i have explicitly written the rules for .c and .o files?

Comment: Your question doesn't say what actually happens when you run make, and it doesn't make clear what you expected to happen that didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `make` without `-r` option, the built-in rule comes in place:

```
%: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

This can be verified with `make -p`:

```
...
program1: program1.c
#  Command line target.
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'program1'
#  Last modified 2019-11-19 14:28:03.247550778
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := program1
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * := program1
# automatic
# + := program1.c
# automatic
# | :=
# automatic
# < := program1.c
# automatic
# ^ := program1.c
# automatic
# ? := program1.c
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/21=5%
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
...
```

This rule is selected over [chain of implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) `%.c -> %.o -> %` as documented:

> There are some special implicit rules to optimize certain cases that would otherwise be handled by rule chains. For example, making `foo` from `foo.c` could be handled by compiling and linking with separate chained rules, using `foo.o` as an intermediate file. But what actually happens is that a special rule for this case does the compilation and linking with a single `cc` command. The optimized rule is used in preference to the step-by-step chain because it comes earlier in the ordering of rules.

Now, when you disable built-in rules with `-r`, old-fashioned rules that you use are also disabled, due to `.SUFFIXES` being empty, as [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules):

> Suffix rule definitions are recognized by comparing each rule’s target against a defined list of known suffixes. When `make` sees a rule whose target is a known suffix, this rule is considered a single-suffix rule.
>
> The known suffixes are simply the names of the prerequisites of the special target `.SUFFIXES`.
>
> The ‘`-r`’ or ‘`--no-builtin-rules`’ flag causes the default list of suffixes to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your question omits some details, but I'll go out on a limb.

You have written a rule for the target `.o`, and a pattern rule for targets of the pattern "%.o". But you are not asking make to build `.o` or `program1.o`, you are asking it to build `program1`. Had you examined the results of running Make, you would have noticed that there is no object file involved.

Comment: Yes, this is intentional that i only have rules for .o files. In the process of building program1 with implicit rule i expect make to use my rules for .c and .o files. Why is it not using my rules? Thanks!